# Can't get value from textinput of ActiveForm in controller after submit under Yii2

Tags: php, forms, post, yii2, active-form

I made a custom model and it is an `Upload Form` which extends `Model`. I made a copy based from yii2's documentation about `UploadedFile` but so far the one is working is the uploaded file when it is saved under `web/uploads`. I made a public property named `$storeList`. I was expecting after I call `$model->load((Yii::$app->request->post())` the value inside the form would be assigned to `$model->storeList` but the variable is just empty. Can someone tell me where I am doing wrong?

The structure goes like this. `index.php` is loaded first and it includes `select_package.php` which has a tab that renders `upload.php`.

index.php:

```
<div id="uploadStatusFrame" class="uploadStatusFrame">
    <?php
        include('layouts/select_package.php');
    ?>
</div>

<button id="uploadButton" class="btn btn-success" 
                style='position:relative; left:10px; top: -44px'>Upload to Server</button>

<script>
$('#uploadButton').click(function(){
    $("#submitButton").trigger("click");
});
</script>
```

select_package.php:

```
<?= 
    Tabs::widget([
        'id' => 'dashboardTab',
        'options' => ['id' => 'mainTab',
                    'class' => 'nav nav-tabs',
                        'style' => 'font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold;border-bottom: none;',
                    ],
        'items' => [
        [
            'label' => 'New Firmware',
            'active' => true,
                'style' => 'font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold',
            'options' => ['id' => 'tab1',
                        'class' => 'nav nav-tabs',
                        'style' => 'width:1044px;margin:1px;background:#428bca; 
                        height:453px;border:2px solid #428bca;'
                        ],
            'content' => $this->render('/upload-package/upload', [
                            'model' => $model,
                        ]),
        ],
    ]);
?>
```

UploadPackageController.php:

```
class UploadPackageController extends Controller
{
    public $layout = "default";

    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'delete' => ['post'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Lists all SystemConfig models.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $model = new UploadForm;

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            $model->imageFile = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'imageFile');
            $model->storeList = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'storeList');     // **<<-- How should I handle this?**

            if ($model->upload()){
                return $this->render('index', [
                    'model' => $model,
                    'storeList' => $model->storeList,
                ]);
            }
        }

        return $this->render('index', [
            'model' => $model,
            'storeList' => 'NONE',
        ]);
    }
}
```

UploadForm.php:

```
class UploadForm extends Model
{
    /**
     * @var UploadedFile
     */
    public $imageFile;
    public $storeList;

    public function rules()
    {
        return [

        ];
    }

    public function upload()
    {
        if ($this->validate()) {
            $this->imageFile->saveAs('uploads/' . $this->imageFile->baseName . '.' . $this->imageFile->extension);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

upload.php

```
    <?= $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',
            'id' => 'fileSenderForm', 
            'name' => 'fileSenderForm', 
        ]]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'imageFile')->fileInput(); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'storeList')->textInput(['value' => 'ANY_VALUE_HERE'])->label(); ?>

    <?= Html::submitButton('Submit', ['id' => 'submitButton']); ?>

    <?php ActiveForm::end() ?>
```

Comment: Remove `$model->storeList = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'storeList');` because it's not an fileinput.

Comment: @InsaneSkull Thanks for the reply but still same problem. $model->storeList is empty. Is it because it's just an include file?

Comment: where you rendering your `upload.php`?

Comment: I tried rendering `upload.php` directly from the controller `UploadPackageController` but the result is still the same. I tried var_dump($model->storeList) and it displays nothing

Comment: you must define proper rules for all attributes and use gii if you find difficulties.

Comment: define rules for your model. i ran into many troubles because of not defining any rules. try doing that first then see if the problem is still there.

Comment: @HussainAlmomen Thanks for the comment Hussain, I also did that but still nothing happened.

I finally fixed the problem by adding this in the controller
            
            `$data = Yii::$app->request->post('UploadForm', []);
            $model->storeList = $data['storeList'];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Your problem and its cause

If you check out the contents of your request, you will see that your value is sent but not assigned into the model. The reason for this is a security-feature of Yii2. What the `load()`-method does is called massive assignment of model attributes. As this could be potentially dangerous, Yii requires all attributes being mass-assigned to be

- validated
- or declared as 'safe' (which in reality also is a validator)

### Solution

So...you need to add the attributes you want to be massive assigned via `$model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())` to the validators. Otherwise they will be skipped. Also remove the `UploadedFile::getInstance` for this field as this attribute obviously is not about a file.

You can either use an actual validator or just declare them as safe. Your rules-method could look like this:

```
public function rules() {
    return [
        [['storeList'], 'string', 'max'=>64],
    ];
}
```

or if you don't want to specify any 'real' validator, just declare the attribute as safe:

```
public function rules() {
    return [
        [['storeList'], 'safe'],
    ];
}
```

### Read about this

You can read all the details about this in the official guide here:

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-models.html#massive-assignment

Comment: very well explained. Thanks mate!